# Return results based on a range of values ie WHERE ColA = (ColB + n OR ColB - n)

Tags: mysql, range, where-clause

I'm a little stuck on the following, may I ask you for some direction please?

I have created 2 temp tables 'compare1' and 'compare2' and I'd like to list words that are common between the tables.

However, in each of the temp tables I have a numeric field, 'chunkIdx', that represents the position of the word. I would like to limit the results I list to be within a specific range of that position.

Let me show you my results, first and an explanation of what is wrong with them ...

```
tSpan   wLen    aSize   c1_chunkIdx word    tSpan   wLen    aSize   c2_chunkIdx word
5       7       6       0           daa     5       7       6       43          daa
5       8       7       1           baa     5       8       7       44          baa
5       7       6       1           baa     5       7       6       1           baa
```

Of the results listed above, I would only want line 3. As the c2_chunkIDx value is between c1_chunkIDx - 5 and c1_chunkIDx + 5. Obviously, Lines 1 and 2 would fail this test.

I thought I could include something like ...

```
WHERE (c2.chunkIdx BETWEEN (c1.chunkIdx - 5) AND (c1.chunkIdx + 5))
```

or perhaps ...

```
WHERE (c2.chunkIdx >= (c1.chunkIdx - 5) OR c2.chunkIdx <= (c1.chunkIdx + 5))
```

In my WHERE clause, but doing so returns nothing. Literally no result tab to even view an empty dataset (I'm using HeidiSQL). It's like the query just never fired, I don't even get an error message.

Clearly I'm missing something (other than just results).

My complete query looks like the following.

```
SELECT c1.tSpan, c1.wLen, c1.aSize, c1.chunkIdx AS C1_ChunkIdx, c1.word,
       c2.tSpan, c2.wLen, c2.aSize, c2.chunkIdx AS C2_ChunkIdx, c2.word
FROM compare1 c1
    INNER JOIN compare2 c2 ON c1.word = c2.word
WHERE (c2.chunkIdx BETWEEN (c1.chunkIdx - 5) AND (c1.chunkIdx + 5))
    AND c1.tSpan = c2.tSpan
    AND c1.wLen = c2.wLen
    AND c1.aSize = c2.aSize
```

May I ask, how can I limit my results to be within a range based on the value of the c1.chunkIdx field?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you have the complete dataset I'd you don't add anything in where? Also fix your brackets, correct order should be: `(...) AND / OR  (...)`

Comment: Are all the numeric columns declared as integers?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Will act upon them as soon as I have tried @Gordon Linoff answer first.

Comment: For some reason I can't add comments to Gordons answer below

Comment: Ahh I see why ... it's gone. Odd. Heidi and I guess mySQL by extension complain of 'unkown column c2.C2_chunkIdx' in the WHERE ... even tho' I have copied and pasted from the Select. However, adding ", @ chunk1 := (c1.chunkIdx + 5), @ chunk2 := (c1.chunkIdx - 5)" to SELECT and "AND c2.chunkIdx <= (@ chunk1) AND c2.chunkIdx >= (@ chunk2)" to the WHERE produces results that I think are correct.

Comment: @Máté Juhász. Yes the complete DS is return if I remove the WHERE conditions.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Yes they are all integers. Both temps tables were created from the same 'master' table. I've learnt to use temps so I don't have to use subqueries as they make my head dizzy.

Comment: I think the answer seems to be setting variables in the SELECT with correct values and then using them in the WHERE. If someone could make that an answer for me I can accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be to use variables

```
SELECT c1.tSpan, c1.wLen, c1.aSize, c1.chunkIdx AS C1_ChunkIdx, c1.word,
   c2.tSpan, c2.wLen, c2.aSize, c2.chunkIdx AS C2_ChunkIdx, c2.word
, @lowChunk := (c1.chunkIdx - 5)
, @highChunk := (c1.chunkIdx + 5)
FROM compare1 c1
    INNER JOIN compare2 c2 ON c1.word = c2.word
WHERE c2.chunkIdx BETWEEN @lowChunk AND @highChunk
    AND c1.tSpan = c2.tSpan
    AND c1.wLen = c2.wLen
    AND c1.aSize = c2.aSize
```

This seems to give me what I need. I'm not a strong SQL man, so I can't explain why this is so.